# iOS6 rotation issue: make my view stick to portrait when pop back from another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, rotation

I have two viewcontrollers, ViewControllerA supports both landscape and portrait, click a button in ViewControllerA push into ViewControllerB, which supports landscape only, then I make the phone in the landscape direction and then pop back to ViewControllerA, by default A is in landscape mode now, but I want it to be portrait first in this situation. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ViewControllerA`'s `viewwillappear` method set the orientation like

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice]setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Comment: @njuxjy: This is undocumented method. Probably app would get rejected by Apple.

Comment: @Maulik yeah, i noticed that, but I'm convinced by my colleague who's sure that it's ok to use it... i'll give it a try.